# "Levelling" elevation data coinciding with polygon?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygon, geoprocessing

I have a shapefile containing building geometries (polygons) and a elevation dataset. The elevation data doesn't perfectly match the buildings.

I want to "flatten" the elevation data so that wherever there's a building the elevation will be completely flat.

In short: For all pixels that intersect a polygon, alter their value to the average of the intersecting pixels.

How can I accomplish that?

This Question is more or less unrelated to a specific software, though I prefer using free software like QGIS, GDAL/OGR etc.

Comment: To keep your Question as focussed as possible I recommend that you explore your preferred options of QGIS/GDAL/OGR first, then if you need to, research/ask about other software separately.

Comment: I recommend the opposite of @PolyGeo and appreciate your effort to make this question widely useful, regardless of the software employed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mean values of elevation in building polygons...

**In QGIS:**

1. Activate *Zonal Statistics* plugin

   - Run it - "Raster/Zonal Statistics", it will add new columns to polygon layer
   - the one needed is "*mean*".
2. Duplicate your elevation layer (raster/grid) - you will use it for final file
3. Use "*Raster / Conversion / Rasterize*"

   - select you polygon (building) layer, field "mean"
   - as target use your copy of elevation raster/grid.
   - Keep existing size and resolution
   - (for some reason my QGIS 2.2 vesion writes "The selected file is not a supported OGR format" for all vector files I tried so I needed to use QGIS dev version 2.3)

The result will be combination of original elevation values outside of polygons and mean inside of polygons.

Comment: +1 This is the correct approach in general: patch the building regions in the DEM with their zonal means. It works in any raster GIS.

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked great. The elevation data I worked with was a 5-degree EU-DEM 30m tile, so Qgis was able to handle a fairly large elevation dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This answer works only if you want constant value - in example 0.

**In QGIS:**

1. Clip elevation by polygons (buildings) to new raster (grid) - buildings_grd

   - *Raster/Extraction/Clipper*
   - (Use Clipping mode "*Mask Layer*" and your building shapefile)
2. Run raster calculator and calculate

   - *Raster/Raster Calculator...*
   - Expression: ("elevation" = "buildings_grd")*0 + ("elevation" != "buildings_grd")*"elevation"

Comment: Oh, I just realized I overlooked the part "alter their value to the average of the intersecting pixels" so there need to be more steps, will think about it and try to complete it.